# Setup multiple sub directories to link with multiple github pages

Tags: github, github-pages, cname

I have a website [Vinay Kumar](https://vinaykumar.tech).
I created a subdomain [Projects](https://projects.vinaykumar.tech) to showcase all my Github projects.
For example, I have repositories names flames, weather, and local news reports each having their own Github pages.
Now I want to create directories flames, weather,localnews in my subdomain.
Is there any way that the link projects.vinaykumar.tech/flames would launch the flames GitHub page without any URL redirections?

I have already tried with simple URL redirections and It is a bit uncomfortable for navigating from one page to another, so I removed it.

I cannot deploy those in my own server because I cannot rely on my server with low configuration which goes down frequently.

Is there any possibility of linking my directories to GitHub pages without URL redirections?

Answer (score 0):

What if, in your "projects" repo, you import the 3 project as git submodules ?

Then, you can deploy your "projects" repo on github pages, and that would build the pages for the 3 projects because they are included in it